# Why below code is valid in JavaScript and not giving compiler error

Tags: javascript

```
for(i=0; i<=10; i++);
{
    document.writeln(i);
}
```

java script is ignoring the braces and printing 11. Why I'm not getting compiler error.

Comment: You shouldn't have the semicolon `;` after the `for` statement.

Answer (score 5):

A `for` loop can be expressed as either:

```
for () ... ;
```

or

```
for () { ... ; ... ; }
```

You've picked the former, except you do *nothing* between the conditions and the `;` that ends the expression which gets evaluated each time you loop.

Then `{ ... }` is a block. There's no reason for it to be a block because you don't do anything inside it at block level (like use `let`).

`document.writeln(i)` writes out the current value of `i`, which is 11 because that is the value `i` hit before it didn't meet the condition `i <= 10`.

---

For the block to be associated with the `for` loop you **must not** have a `;` before it.